# Tracking function execution time with jasmine

Tags: javascript, performance, testing, jasmine, protractor

Is it possible to create a reusable *jasmine matcher* that would assert a function to run for less than N seconds?

Sample expectation style:

```
expect(someFunction, [arg1, arg2]).toBeCompletedForLessThan(3);
expect(obj.someMethod, [arg1, arg2]).toBeCompletedForLessThan(5);
```

---

We'd like to tie this up with Protractor and custom performance tests where we want to assert that certain UI execution steps don't go beyond the time limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would measure the elapsed time with a custom timer and then assert the result with `.toBeLessThan`:

```
var timer = Timer();

$("#mytext").getText().then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
});

expect(timer.elapsed).toBeLessThan(1000);   // to be under 1 second
```

The timer:

```
var Timer = function() {
  var starttime = 0;

  browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    starttime = Date.now()
  });

  return {
    get elapsed() {
      return browser.controlFlow().execute(() => Date.now() - starttime);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Looks very promising and logical. I'll try that in practice. Thanks again.